# Show first tab when page is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs, click

I hope somebody can help me to load the first tab (make it active) when the page is loaded. Now the jquery tabs only works fine after clicking.

I'm using this code:

HTML

```
<a class="link" href="#" rel="div1">Tab 1</a>
<a class="link" href="#" rel="div2">Tab 2</a>

<div class="content5" id="div1">Content of Tab 1</div>
<div class="content5" id="div2">Content of Tab 2</div>
```

Javascript/Jquery

```
$('.link').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var content = $(this).attr('rel');
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('.content5').hide();
    $('#' + content).show();
});​
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.link:first').addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: This, or whatever class UI tabs add to the active tab

Comment: Thank you. It works! Only the second tab content (div2) is not hidden after the page is loaded. I tried to put $('.content5 #div2').hide(); in the ready function but it's not working.
EDIT: Sorry still solved with: $('.content5:last').hide();.

Answer (score 1):

I would encapsulate the display logic;

```
function showTab(jqEl) {
    var content = jqEl.attr('rel');
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    jqEl.addClass('active');
    $('.content5').hide();
    $('#' + content).show();
};
```

The call as needed;

```
$('.link').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    showTab($(this));
});
```

and

```
$().ready(function() {
  showTab($(".link[rel=div1]")); //or better
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger a click on the first link after the binding:

```
$('.link')
    .click(function(e) {
        ...
    })
    .first().click(); // or .trigger('click')
```

[.click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/) / [.trigger('click')](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

Answer (score 0):

Just use HTML and CSS to make it visible, i.e:

Tab 1
Tab 2

Content of Tab 1

Content of Tab 2

So the first link starts out with a class of `active`, and the first tab starts out as visible via `display:block`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you wrap the Code in a function? call the function from inside the event, passing in thr object $(this). Call the function on page load passing in ('.link').first()

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure which jquery you are using but in simple way try to load the tab in page        load as below:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#tabs").tabs({ selected: 1 });
        });
```