# Applying default focus on anchor (from a list of 5 anchors)

Tags: jquery, css

I have a question

I have made 5 anchors behave like "tabs". Basically you click on them to view different page content. Now my question is, I am using css :focus to allow the color to change on click. This is used to allow the user to see which current anchor he is currently in.

Now my problem here is I want one of the anchors to be highlighted by the same focus rule by default (the anchor is for home) since by default, on page load, we are already in that anchor.

Would really apperciate some of your advice, thank you

Just to be more clear, say we got 5 anchors
a1 | a2 | a3 | a4 | a5
now on page load, I want to apply the focus css rule to a1 since 
its the default, the rest will change depending on which the user clicks on

What I have currently works however the problem is it by default does not focus on any tab. Once the user clicks on some tab it will change which is correct. Its just I was hoping to get a default tab

Comment: First do some google as its already asked on SO, second please come with code you have tried. Thank you.

Comment: I didnt find it on google, can you tell me what you searched?

Comment: you can have idea from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9482440/show-first-tab-when-page-is-loaded) and [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/how-to-keep-the-tab-active-when-the-user-come-page-to-page/16643)

Comment: Thanks man, I will look both of them now

Comment: Yea thats a skill man. It is always easier to search for something you already know or you search for something thats new to you...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
    $('#a1').click();
    // This will execute on page load and when click is done the focus css applied on this anchor automatically

OR

    $('#a1').addClass('focus');
    // make a css class and add to any anchor
});
```